# How can I run unity with Slim with sound

Tags: 11.10, unity, sound, slim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is SLiM (simple login manager) compatible with 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80004/is-slim-simple-login-manager-compatible-with-11-10)

I'm trying to start the unity environment from slim display manager, everything goes fine, except by the sound that don't work, the device just dont appear in the device list

I already changed the slim config file to start with this code below, but it didnt solve the problem....

```
login_cmd exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch /bin/bash -login /etc/X11/Xsession %session
```

I believe the it is related with some thing that the gdm/lighdm start with the session and slim dont do that

When I use the lighdm or gdm to start the environment everything works fine