# is SLiM (simple login manager) compatible with 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, login, slim

I have been reading about SLiM and am wondering if I were to install it in ubuntu 11.10 if it is compatible or if it would cause serious issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slim hasn't seen any update since September 2005. It may work for sessions that haven't changed since then but it has the following shortcomings:

- Does not initialize policykit
- Does not unlock the seahorse or gnupg key vaults
- Does not start any DBus-related things

In short, if you are going to use desktops in the range of twm, windowmaker, openbox, it surely is a lightweight choice but you will witness serious degradation if you are headed for gnome, kde, unity or xfce.

Comment: Thats grand, thanks for the reply, its a shame, looks pretty cool, lightDM it is then.