# how do i install SLiM login manager?

Tags: login-screen

I would like to know the easiest and most straight forward way to to install the SLiM login manager. hopefully through terminal, but I am  not fussy how I install it correctly as long as it works.

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and slim login manager is a very lightweight login manager, with some connections to both awesome and DWM window manager.

Comment: You might want to explain briefly what that is, and why you need/want it...

Comment: you should add your ubuntu version - if its 11.10 or later, you need to be aware of this Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/80004/is-slim-simple-login-manager-compatible-with-11-10

Comment: i have just added the additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install `slim`:

```
sudo apt-get install slim
```

If you change your mind later, and want to fall back to the default login manager back:

*Ubuntu 11.04 and later:*

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

*Before Ubuntu 11.04:*

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Comment: But be aware, as *fossfreedom* commented, it's probably not a wise idea to use this login manager :)